# Why should Meteor MUP Setup behave different in private network

Tags: meteor, ubuntu-18.04, meteor-up, private-network

I have a **Ubuntu 18.04 Server** VM with a public ip and also another VM in the private network (I am also located in the private network and can ssh into the server; no VPN involved).

I have pushed dozens of **Meteor 1.8.1** apps to our public VMs without any issues using the same process:

- `mup init`
- config `mup.js` and `settings.json`
- `mup setup`
- `mup deploy`

Now when I use the private-located VM (ip `10.x.y.z`) then I get the following error on `mup setup`:

```sh
$ meteor mup setup 

Started TaskList: Setup Docker
[10.x.y.z] - Setup Docker
[10.x.y.z] x Setup Docker: FAILED

              ------------------------------------STDERR------------------------------------
              sudo: docker: command not found
        sudo: docker: command not found
        debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
        debconf: (Dialog frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or without a controlling terminal.)
        debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
        debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
        debconf: (This frontend requires a controlling tty.)
        debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
        dpkg-preconfigure: unable to re-open stdin: 
        usermod: group 'docker' does not exist
```

Where the line `Dialog frontend will not work on a dumb terminal, an emacs shell buffer, or without a controlling terminal` makes me curious, since this should not be caused due to being in a private network, am I right?

mup.js is

```js
module.exports = {
  servers: {
    one: {
      host: '10.x.y.z',
      username: 'root'
    }
  },

  app: {
    name: 'appname',
    path: '../',

    servers: {
      one: {},
    },

    buildOptions: {
      serverOnly: true,
    },

    env: {
      ROOT_URL: 'https://ref.to.domain.tld',
      MONGO_URL: 'mongodb://localhost/meteor',
      MONGO_OPLOG_URL: 'mongodb://mongodb/local',
      HTTP_FORWARDED_COUNT: 1,
      port: 12345
    },

    docker: {
      image: 'abernix/meteord:node-8.15.1-base',
    },

    // Show progress bar while uploading bundle to server
    // You might need to disable it on CI servers
    enableUploadProgressBar: true
  },

  mongo: {
    version: '3.4.1',
    servers: {
      one: {}
    }
  },

  // (Optional)
  // Use the proxy to setup ssl or to route requests to the correct
  // app when there are several apps

  proxy: {
    domains: 'ref.to.domain.tld',
    ssl: {
      forceSSL: true,
      letsEncryptEmail: 'user@example.tld'
    },
    clientUploadLimit: '50M'
  }
};
```

Why is this? I can't get a reason for why it should behave so different while the VM does not differ besides the network config?

Comment: The errors may be a result of it trying to get around a problem... `usermod: group 'docker' does not exist` may be a clue - is the image you are using incompatible? Is it failing to install something on that server (due to firewall restrictions?) Do you need to set up proxies to allow that?

Comment: Sounds unrelated to the private network. What OS is running on that VM? I suspect it is missing some required dependencies

Comment: It's the same base snapshot of an Ubuntu 18.04 server and all other deployment using the same snapshot were fine. The only real difference is the network stack. The docker group is not there because the docker install part of `mup install` did not succeed.

Comment: MUP is unable to install Docker because Dialog, Redline and Teletype will not run on the dumb terminal.  Try SSHing onto the server and run `wget -qO- https://get.docker.com/ | sudo sh` -> https://github.com/zodern/meteor-up/issues/737